# Variadic template and template template (probably a compiler issue related to CUDA)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I try to write the small template function `make` to facilitate the construction of some functors following the same structure as `Functor`. Works fine as follows for a functor with one argument:

```
template <class ARG1>
struct Functor{
    Functor(ARG1 x){ }
};

template <template <class> class FCT, class ARG>
FCT<ARG> make(ARG arg){
    return FCT<ARG>(arg);
}

void main(){
    int a = 5;
    make<Functor>(a);
}
```

Now I try to extend `make` to use it for functors with any number of arguments, for example the now two argument functor `Functor`:

```
template <class ARG1, class ARG2>
struct Functor{
    Functor(ARG1 x, ARG2 y){ }
};

template <template <class, class...> class FCT, class... ARG>
FCT<ARG...> make(ARG... arg){
    return FCT<ARG...>(arg...);
}

void main(){
    int a = 5;
    double b = 6;
    make<Functor>(a, b);
}
```

That does not work any longer, compiler says:

> basic.cpp(199): error: no instance of function template "make" matches
>   the argument list
>               argument types are: (int, double)

Honestly, I have no idea what's wrong here. I do not see a conceptional difference to the first example. What do I need to do to make it work?

Some further investigation, based on comments:

It works fine when directly compiling the code as `main.cpp` with g++-4.8.3:

```
/path/to/g++-4.8.3 -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

It issues the error when compiling the code as `main.cu` via nvcc using g++-4.8.3:

```
/path/to/cuda/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc main.cu -o experiments_cuda -O0 -g -ccbin=/path/to/g++-4.8.3 --compiler-options='-std=c++11' -std=c++11
```

Furthermore, it works fine when compiling the code as `main.cpp`via nvcc:

```
/path/to/cuda/cuda-6.5/bin/nvcc main.cpp -o experiments_cuda -O0 -g -ccbin=/path/to/g++-4.8.3 --compiler-options='-std=c++11' -std=c++11
```

The C++ 11 flags seem to be passed correctly - if I remove them, I get way more errors.

Comment: Seems to [work as indented](https://ideone.com/uOEwKD) after fixing the usual newbie mistakes.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I feel like a blind person here... what did you change? `void main` to `int main` is what I've spotted.... (I should be a real programmer and just diff the code).

Comment: I may also have switched to a C++11 compiler :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, it seems to be related to the compiler in peculiar manner. I edited it into the question.

Comment: Pass `-cuda` and let's see what `nvcc` is feeding to `g++`.

Comment: @T.C.: I was looking for something like that. It's difficult to phrase and therefore difficult to google... Where do I have to put `-cuda` exactly?

Comment: Should be to `nvcc`, so `nvcc -cuda main.cu ...`

Comment: Gives a long *.ii file. I take the part corresponding to main.cu, copy it into a *.cpp file, compile it and it works fine... Only when exactly the same code is in a *.cu file, I have a problem. Same flags and everything.

Comment: Just for my understanding: `nvcc` will take the *.cu file, translate the CUDA-specific syntax into C++ and pass that code to the compiler given by `-ccbin`? That would mean that `nvcc` also has to do other "code-level" stuff like instantiating templates. So I would assume that `nvcc` can not handle my template in that step? (Workaround: Define a template of `make(...)` for any possible number of arguments. Not that bad.)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's that `nvcc` requires `--std c++11` rather than `--std=c++11`?

Comment: Both seem to be equal. (I do not want to downvote it, but that's really not an answer.)